# How to add JSON data to my datatable if I have 3 nested data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datatable

How to add the JSON file that are nested to the datatable i created.
I always encounter this problem:

> DataTables warning: table id=tb_friendlist - Invalid JSON response.
> For more information about this error, please see
> http://datatables.net/tn/1

HTML

```
<table id="tb_friendlist" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Steam ID</th>
            <th>Relationship</th>
            <th>Friend Since</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
          
          <th>Steam ID</th>
          <th>Relationship</th>
          <th>Friend Since</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

JS/JQuery I'm Using:

```
$.ajax({            
    type : 'GET', 
    url: 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&relationship=friend&format=json&steamid=76561197960435530',
   
    success : function(data){        
        console.log(data.friendslist);
        $('#tb_friendlist').DataTable( {
            "ajax": data,
            "columns": [
                { "data": data.friendslist.friends.steam_id },
                { "data": data.friendslist.friends.relationship },
                { "data": data.friendslist.friends.friend_since }
            ]
        } );
    }
});
```

JSON File:

```
{"friendslist":{"friends":[{"steamid":"76561197960265731","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960265738","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960265740","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960265744","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1585508613},{"steamid":"76561197960265747","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960265749","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960268093","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1251433222},{"steamid":"76561197960269040","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1436934825},{"steamid":"76561197960270258","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960270457","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1257142334},{"steamid":"76561197960271661","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1327552405},{"steamid":"76561197960273963","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960274006","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960274521","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1283486787},{"steamid":"76561197960279106","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1252902778},{"steamid":"76561197960282696","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960282709","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960299622","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960304647","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960317684","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1251865307},{"steamid":"76561197960323774","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960333589","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960359661","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960389850","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1327992364},{"steamid":"76561197960392503","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1366092272},{"steamid":"76561197960411603","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1346991873},{"steamid":"76561197960423941","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960434622","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1278879949},{"steamid":"76561197960491601","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1230537028},{"steamid":"76561197960505737","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1327552425},{"steamid":"76561197960508417","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1298569205},{"steamid":"76561197960522471","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1230537024},{"steamid":"76561197960529298","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1390366452},{"steamid":"76561197960549564","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960563532","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960568847","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1333079735},{"steamid":"76561197960575737","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1331440292},{"steamid":"76561197960691398","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1333079737},{"steamid":"76561197960789988","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960860649","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197960879472","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1331440322},{"steamid":"76561197961004348","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1233376941},{"steamid":"76561197961016107","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1299561164},{"steamid":"76561197961048326","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1305088151},{"steamid":"76561197961301890","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197961322701","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1562736913},{"steamid":"76561197961456983","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1436936650},{"steamid":"76561197961493110","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1530844814},{"steamid":"76561197961513395","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197961567067","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1280805626},{"steamid":"76561197961635855","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1305088152},{"steamid":"76561197961697514","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1328471606},{"steamid":"76561197961725694","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1249447084},{"steamid":"76561197961903764","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1238215828},{"steamid":"76561197961963491","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1335800301},{"steamid":"76561197961987005","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1261202570},{"steamid":"76561197962090766","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1545426885},{"steamid":"76561197962095245","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1450768354},{"steamid":"76561197962205142","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1246690451},{"steamid":"76561197962313932","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197962413930","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1452293804},{"steamid":"76561197962783665","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197962833771","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1246340239},{"steamid":"76561197962844216","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197963562041","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1300220501},{"steamid":"76561197963585314","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197963687679","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1251777207},{"steamid":"76561197964165126","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1451974958},{"steamid":"76561197964770089","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1325652265},{"steamid":"76561197964865846","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197965400579","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1509136774},{"steamid":"76561197965532939","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1350963678},{"steamid":"76561197965576021","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1258548993},{"steamid":"76561197965640811","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1267240082},{"steamid":"76561197965656609","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1347214065},{"steamid":"76561197965686610","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1312001126},{"steamid":"76561197966056073","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1234811002},{"steamid":"76561197966089529","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1348200708},{"steamid":"76561197966106312","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197966109336","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1284524815},{"steamid":"76561197966589084","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197966591880","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1282803048},{"steamid":"76561197966652320","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197967027289","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197967346751","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1419372025},{"steamid":"76561197967377359","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1375241965},{"steamid":"76561197967454254","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197967823929","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1268222378},{"steamid":"76561197968282875","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197968304048","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197968343660","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197968403639","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1274246179},{"steamid":"76561197968411673","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1258327120},{"steamid":"76561197968452293","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197968459473","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1286855142},{"steamid":"76561197968493120","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1318097746},{"steamid":"76561197968499581","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1298522642},{"steamid":"76561197968575517","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1283140137},{"steamid":"76561197968662512","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1243048442},{"steamid":"76561197968887855","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197969013812","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1320344898},{"steamid":"76561197969044631","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1283486596},{"steamid":"76561197969204208","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197969221324","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1261119417},{"steamid":"76561197969266938","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1285385050},{"steamid":"76561197969321754","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1599851854},{"steamid":"76561197969363440","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197969363506","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197969389470","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197969507292","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1580456777},{"steamid":"76561197969518075","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1287104617},{"steamid":"76561197969593376","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1251777234},{"steamid":"76561197970125572","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197970166754","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1283486539},{"steamid":"76561197970188759","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1258311040},{"steamid":"76561197970280218","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1254978747},{"steamid":"76561197970282885","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1591890829},{"steamid":"76561197970323416","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1272505770},{"steamid":"76561197970389205","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197970404169","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1260340950},{"steamid":"76561197970496388","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197970498549","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1305400189},{"steamid":"76561197970522250","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1252469387},{"steamid":"76561197970545345","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197970553411","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1280805662},{"steamid":"76561197970565175","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197970572119","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1262234024},{"steamid":"76561197970610844","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197970667119","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1331440337},{"steamid":"76561197970792670","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1252469394},{"steamid":"76561197970822785","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197970953718","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197970968871","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1414954611},{"steamid":"76561197971025345","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1333079747},{"steamid":"76561197971057511","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1312778874},{"steamid":"76561197971085582","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1356718664},{"steamid":"76561197971124276","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197971128200","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1254974887},{"steamid":"76561197971238476","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1249447170},{"steamid":"76561197971332340","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1347679040},{"steamid":"76561197971400048","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1336893966},{"steamid":"76561197971521071","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1455533991},{"steamid":"76561197971951755","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197972291076","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1585508607},{"steamid":"76561197972345559","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1278650650},{"steamid":"76561197972495328","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1380689769},{"steamid":"76561197972790745","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1244528575},{"steamid":"76561197972799883","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1346896735},{"steamid":"76561197973185198","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1257142395},{"steamid":"76561197973639804","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197974284838","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1295845647},{"steamid":"76561197974616601","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1319599842},{"steamid":"76561197974777179","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1289893342},{"steamid":"76561197974807412","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197975724041","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1337920161},{"steamid":"76561197975914763","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197976244853","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1299561095},{"steamid":"76561197977035150","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197977450070","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1347343394},{"steamid":"76561197978181900","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1234074199},{"steamid":"76561197978236369","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1258442642},{"steamid":"76561197978266558","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1418699542},{"steamid":"76561197979187556","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197979435127","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1236474691},{"steamid":"76561197979480245","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1305088194},{"steamid":"76561197979536477","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1246340263},{"steamid":"76561197980388693","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1275536464},{"steamid":"76561197981291930","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1334029416},{"steamid":"76561197982240193","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197982656766","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1257142470},{"steamid":"76561197982998220","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1316632423},{"steamid":"76561197983491300","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197983540634","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1347896489},{"steamid":"76561197984212648","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1524288546},{"steamid":"76561197984476370","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1252037969},{"steamid":"76561197985244272","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197985279592","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197985536977","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1350704086},{"steamid":"76561197985866466","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1289893378},{"steamid":"76561197986695451","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1244788670},{"steamid":"76561197987101307","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1274940404},{"steamid":"76561197987393094","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1298522644},{"steamid":"76561197988042654","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1265486190},{"steamid":"76561197988052879","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1373949178},{"steamid":"76561197988197730","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1276488085},{"steamid":"76561197988221501","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1283451661},{"steamid":"76561197989222171","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1377143565},{"steamid":"76561197989701891","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1316837417},{"steamid":"76561197989870485","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197990525201","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1252469413},{"steamid":"76561197990859622","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197990949369","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1230537020},{"steamid":"76561197991390878","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197991518342","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1347601219},{"steamid":"76561197991751968","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197991840415","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1479705086},{"steamid":"76561197991899002","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1286082214},{"steamid":"76561197992152522","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1280287926},{"steamid":"76561197992219796","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1311828146},{"steamid":"76561197992295963","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1278650658},{"steamid":"76561197992459511","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1291491332},{"steamid":"76561197992577188","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197992594628","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197992720132","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197992927490","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197993345099","relationship":"friend","friend_since":0},{"steamid":"76561197993552969","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1286082108},{"steamid":"76561197993620247","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1263011646},{"steamid":"76561197993630232","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1249148398},{"steamid":"76561197993751379","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1283486349},{"steamid":"76561197994223774","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1299734097},{"steamid":"76561197994242870","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1347937824},{"steamid":"76561197994359533","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1276230703},{"steamid":"76561197994365894","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1294605278},{"steamid":"76561197994871291","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1372582055},{"steamid":"76561197994894204","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1335159140},{"steamid":"76561197995035454","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1330072067},{"steamid":"76561197995390971","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1296715379},{"steamid":"76561197995557785","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1356718679},{"steamid":"76561197995620521","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1242272781},{"steamid":"76561197996055531","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1358916974},{"steamid":"76561197996226415","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1352804786},{"steamid":"76561197996599994","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1298522768},{"steamid":"76561197997296694","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1250832422},{"steamid":"76561197997348592","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1567223810},{"steamid":"76561197997374662","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1274246279},{"steamid":"76561197997412731","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1346896747},{"steamid":"76561197997491987","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1252728718},{"steamid":"76561197998048607","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1283486669},{"steamid":"76561197998113407","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1285649640},{"steamid":"76561197998287308","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1316499408},{"steamid":"76561197998342021","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1286338395},{"steamid":"76561197998653180","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1376112288},{"steamid":"76561197999644177","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1335800276},{"steamid":"76561197999825207","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1449120235},{"steamid":"76561198000167056","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1274246426},{"steamid":"76561198000175595","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1241840395},{"steamid":"76561198000198761","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1274246470},{"steamid":"76561198000613320","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1609138583},{"steamid":"76561198000778598","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1383625609},{"steamid":"76561198002118002","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1343104953},{"steamid":"76561198002524224","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1449120327},{"steamid":"76561198002826921","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1299561235},{"steamid":"76561198004860018","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1290812641},{"steamid":"76561198006930795","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1370242583},{"steamid":"76561198007105082","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1290812487},{"steamid":"76561198007754155","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1290812651},{"steamid":"76561198009095613","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1325652348},{"steamid":"76561198009246617","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1530164209},{"steamid":"76561198010062752","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1351306468},{"steamid":"76561198010168695","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1248755147},{"steamid":"76561198011246300","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1330192563},{"steamid":"76561198011742416","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1348542115},{"steamid":"76561198012882785","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1331440377},{"steamid":"76561198013560482","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1283486799},{"steamid":"76561198014254115","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1254806199},{"steamid":"76561198014273977","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1347773002},{"steamid":"76561198015234450","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1351306412},{"steamid":"76561198026562132","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1346715463},{"steamid":"76561198026610207","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1346739192},{"steamid":"76561198027956837","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1316052135},{"steamid":"76561198031319803","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1363325130},{"steamid":"76561198031708819","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1372582136},{"steamid":"76561198037225309","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1297316926},{"steamid":"76561198037252562","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1346219433},{"steamid":"76561198040984261","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1445142960},{"steamid":"76561198042468117","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1347491840},{"steamid":"76561198042665686","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1453440326},{"steamid":"76561198045945967","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1350704096},{"steamid":"76561198046379753","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1370242520},{"steamid":"76561198046983307","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1346817023},{"steamid":"76561198047404672","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1454562868},{"steamid":"76561198050396055","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1318826201},{"steamid":"76561198059223364","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1468562520},{"steamid":"76561198065538643","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1448169802},{"steamid":"76561198072330588","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1387764448},{"steamid":"76561198075307934","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1446007075},{"steamid":"76561198085350447","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1362335241},{"steamid":"76561198090691972","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1581753542},{"steamid":"76561198109901633","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1418699578},{"steamid":"76561198113967572","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1383948235},{"steamid":"76561198119266856","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1403374765},{"steamid":"76561198829441805","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1580526105},{"steamid":"76561198851945186","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1559687431},{"steamid":"76561199013049287","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1577157657},{"steamid":"76561199064639120","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1605227570},{"steamid":"76561199147650161","relationship":"friend","friend_since":1614836906}]}}
```

Comment: `data.friendslist.friends` is an array

Comment: @ThumChoonTat how to work with this sir? Do i need to use `parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the `friendslist` object as the data source, pass in the `friendslist.friends` array

```js
// lets take 5 friends as an example
var data = {
    "friendslist": {
        "friends": [
              { "steamid": "76561197960265731", "relationship": "friend", "friend_since": 0          }
            , { "steamid": "76561197960265738", "relationship": "friend", "friend_since": 0          }
            , { "steamid": "76561197960265740", "relationship": "friend", "friend_since": 0          }
            , { "steamid": "76561197960265744", "relationship": "friend", "friend_since": 1585508613 }
            , { "steamid": "76561197960265747", "relationship": "friend", "friend_since": 0          }
        ]
    }
};
$('#tb_friendlist').DataTable( {
      data    : data.friendslist.friends
    , columns : [
          { "data": 'steamid'      }
        , { "data": 'relationship' }
        , { "data": 'friend_since' }
    ]
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tb_friendlist" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Steam ID</th>
            <th>Relationship</th>
            <th>Friend Since</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
          
          <th>Steam ID</th>
          <th>Relationship</th>
          <th>Friend Since</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide array in ajax datatable call

```
$.ajax({            
    type : 'GET', 
    url: 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&relationship=friend&format=json&steamid=76561197960435530',
   
    success : function(data){        
        console.log(data.friendslist);
        $('#tb_friendlist').DataTable( {
            "data": data.friendslist.friends,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "steam_id" },
                { "data": "relationship" },
                { "data": "friend_since" }
            ]
        } );
    }
});
```

This might solve your problem

Comment: Krunal i got this `DataTables warning: table id=tb_friendlist - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1`